# Kali Linux java

Tags: linux, java, sandbox, exploit

I have a Kali linux sandbox set up with a direct connection to a windows VM. I have JAR files / java exploits I want to serve using the Kali box. After I get the jar file into the Kali Box, I know I have to create an html (nano.html). Can anyone tell me what I need to put within that html to serve the java exploit?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add to the question what you already tried and why it's not working? I assume you have Googled something like 'embed java into html', so why the question?

Comment: I used <applet archive="jar file" code="swjahd.class" - when I connect to it, nothing happens. but if I do <applet code="swjahd.class" and remove the archive="jar file" it executes, but I would just have to do it per class file

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the archive (that's how it gets the classes). To specify the "per class" aspect, change the code attribute.

```
<!-- that is swjahd.class is your class; you still need to
     get that class. Jar files are how that is done. -->
<applet archive="jar file" code="swjahd.class"
```